# componentDidMount updating synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm loading data from saved session using:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')) !== null) {
        this.setState({
            cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')),
            totalPrice: this.getPriceOnLoad(),
            totalItems: this.getItemsOnLoad(),
        });
    }
}
```

`cartItems` is an array of objects. Which seems is updated before

```
this.getPriceOnLoad();
this.getItemsOnLoad();
```

functions are called, for example `this.getPriceOnLoad` function:

```
getPriceOnLoad() {
    let itemsPrice = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.cartItems.length - 1; i++) {
        itemsPrice += this.state.cartItems[i].quantity * this.state.cartItems[i].price;
    }
    return itemsPrice;
}
```

but, in `getPriceOnLoad` function, `this.state.cartItems.length` is equal to 0, so for loop is not executing. I can see in React dev tools that this array has some length. Is it because `componentDidMount()` is executing state change synchronously and can't see updated array immediately? So my question is how could i update price and quantity of items after array is initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your state is not updated in order. For this, you could store the `cartItems` in a temporary value, and send it to each functions :

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')) !== null) {
        const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'))
        this.setState({
            cartItems, //Short syntax for 'cartItems: cartItems'
            totalPrice: this.getPriceOnLoad(cartItems),
            totalItems: this.getItemsOnLoad(cartItems),
        });
    }
}
```

You could also make your function significantly shorter by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
this.setState({
    cartItems,
    totalPrice: cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.quantity * item.price), 0),
    totalItems: cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0),
});
```

<strike>Can you show us your second function too ? It may be optimized as well.</strike> Done.

Comment: `getItemsOnLoad() {
        let itemsQuantity = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.cartItems.length - 1; i++) {
            itemsQuantity += this.state.cartItems[i].quantity;
        }
        return itemsQuantity;
    }`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I encountered another similar problem. When I update my cart,(just a function adding another object to an array) and calling 
`const cartItems = this.state.cartItems;
this.setState({
    cartItems,
    totalPrice: cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.quantity * item.price), 0),
    totalItems: cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0),
});`

It looks like `cartItems` is not yet updated. So it dosn't count latest item.Which for me dosn't make sense since yours solution works in the same way as I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 2):

the wrong thing that you are doing is trying to use values from the state on your functions that will define your state.

you have 2 approaches to solve this:

1) use the callback function from `setState` and then set the state again with the new data (which into my opinion is not the best approach)

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')) !== null) {
        const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'))
        this.setState({
            cartItems
        }, ()=> {
           this.setState({
            totalPrice: this.getPriceOnLoad(cartItems),
            totalItems: this.getItemsOnLoad(cartItems),
           });
        })
    }
}
```

2) send the values to your functions

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData')) !== null) {
        const savedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'))
        this.setState({
            cartItems,
            totalPrice: this.getPriceOnLoad(savedCartItems),
            totalItems: this.getItemsOnLoad(savedCartItems),
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getPriceOnLoad()` is executed before this.setState is executed. So you cannot refer to `this.state` in `getPriceOnLoad()`.

When you call `this.setState({})`, JS first needs to generate the object for the `setState()` function. Means the functions you are referring to run first, then `this.setState()`.

And in any case `this.setState()` is an asynchronous function, so `this.state` is not directly available after `setState()` execution.